# Ruby: Take input and take it as loop range

Tags: ruby

```
a = $stdin.read
for i in 0..(a)
puts "Hi"
end
```

This is giving syntax error-in `
': bad value for range (ArgumentError). What should be improved to get output for a=3 as

```
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

Comment: [`ArgumentError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/ArgumentError.html) is not a syntax error. It's raised when you are passing wrong or unexpected parameters. Your syntax is fine.

Comment: ArgumentError is definitely not a SyntaxError and is not a syntax error.  It is indeed an argument error.

Comment: What are you expecting to measure with your value of `a` you are not showing the input expected, so your question actually is hard to decipher beyond the error that you are getting, and yet the error you are getting is actually very clear.

Comment: i just want to print "Hi" for a times, so if a is 3, print Hi for 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because `a` is a string, you can make it an integer by:

```
a = a.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string to an integer (`.to_i`).

Note: prefer to use [`times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Integer.html#method-i-times):

```
a.to_i.times { puts "Hi" }
```

Comment: `a` is originally `String`.

Comment: ': undefined method `times' for "3":String (NoMethodError)
when use times

Comment: a is a number example 3

Comment: a is definitely a string, you need to read the documentation on `read`

Comment: how to take integer from stdin or how to convert a string to interger immediatly after reading it from stdin

Comment: @user3388005 you always enter characters with your keyboard. The application has to *interpret* these characters as an integer, e.g. by calling `input.to_i` to `Integer(input)`

Answer (score 0):

You need an integer to be used, or you get the `ArgumentError`.  This will accept your input and ensure that it can be converted to an Integer.  You can read about the [Kernel#Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method for specifics.

```
a = Integer($stdin.read)
for i in 0..(a)
  puts "Hi"
end
```

Comment: no, i want to take input as integer like 3 and then print Hi for 3 times

Comment: That is a better question than what you have shown actually.  Very specific.